# How to block update action in SVN

Tags: svn, hook

Im trying to disable the commit action in svn, to allow only Add action to especific folder in repository.

My Ideia is to use a SVN HOok, with the pre-commit. First i need to get the file name then im gona check with dos command if the file exist in repository.
I dont know how to get the filename.

Comment: Not sure I understand how this would work? Adding a file needs a commit as well in order to complete. Do you mean, you want to block existing files from being updated?

Comment: Yes i want to block existing files from being updated

Comment: Have you managed to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at svnlook. For example:

```
 > svnlook dirs-changed /path/to/repo/ -t 180000
 directory/changed
 other_directory/changed
```

You can use a regex to determine what's allowed, and use it in a pre-commit hook (return 0 if it's ok, otherwise 1).

EDIT: Sorry, should have added that the current repos and transaction are available as the first and second arguments to the hook script.